# will "gem update --system" update rails from 2.3.8 to 3.0?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If'n I had a 2nd computer I would just do it and see - but I've finely tuned this thing to not run 3.0 just yet ... don't want to muck it up. Took hours & hours to get here. Bascially - I want to keep rails at 2.3.8 for a while ... so will

> gem update --system

update rails from version 2 -> 3? I did read the docs with no clear answer and am guessing it will, but hey, might learn something new.
Otherwise I update each one (of the 8 - 1) gems that I have.
thanks...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`gem update --system` only updates RubyGems.

`gem update` will update all installed gems to their latest versions, so it  will update Rails to 3.0.0.

Before updating the gems you can freeze your application to rails 2.3.8 by executing

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

in your application folder. Thus your application will be associated and run in rails 2.3.8 environment, even if you update the global gem to rails 3.

You can at any time install a specific rails version via:

```
gem install rails -v 2.3.8 (or another version of your choice)
```

This will potentially install multiple gem versions simultaneously, so you can create and develop an app with whichever version you're comfortable with.

Or you can install `RVM` to create and switch between any number of ruby/rails development environments, e.g. Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.9 and ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3.0.0 and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I had not understood that it would only update RubyGems, learned lots, and some great other information that tied things together for me.

Answer (score 6):

That command should just update the RubyGems software, not the gems that you have installed.

From command line help:

```
→ gem help update
Usage: gem update GEMNAME [GEMNAME ...] [options]

  Options:
      --system                     Update the RubyGems system software
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not understood that, in reading I just zipped thru the docs and made an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you [switch your project to use bundler](http://gembundler.com/), then you can stop worrying about this. [It's easy (and well tested) to do with Rails 2.3.8](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) and [it's designed to solve this problem](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html).

Your next best bet is to [install RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) and [use gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/). Alternately, you can check out [rip](http://github.com/defunkt/rip).

---

(I know this doesn't directly answer your question - I was going to post this as a comment, but with the amount of content I wanted to put it in, my only choice was to provide an answer.)

Comment: Excellent! I have a project under 2.3.8 and want to now start delving into 3.0. I had tried two ruby versions together and things sucked, so spent a fair amount of time getting back to where I wanted. This recommendation is cool, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

theIV has answered this admirably and correctly, but I happened to be in a unique position to very specifically address your question, so here you go:

> C:>gem list --local | find "rails"
>
> rails (2.3.5)
>
> C:>gem update --system
>
> Updating
>   RubyGems Updating rubygems-update
>   Successfully installed
>   rubygems-update-1.3.7 Updating
>   RubyGems to 1.3.7 Installing RubyGems
>   1.3.7 RubyGems 1.3.7 installed
>
> ∩╗┐=== 1.3.7 / 2010-05-13
>
> NOTE:
>
> http://rubygems.org is now the default
>   source for downloading gems.
>
> You may have sources set via ~/.gemrc,
>   so you should replace
>   http://gems.rubyforge.org with
>   http://rubygems.org
>
> http://gems.rubyforge.org will
>   continue to work for the forseeable
>   future.
>
> New features:
>
> - `gem` commands   * `gem install` and `gem fetch` now report alternate
>     platforms when a
>     matching one couldn't be found.   * `gem contents` --prefix is now the default as specified in --help.  Bug
>
>   ## 27211 by Mamoru Tasaka.   * `gem fetch` can fetch of old versions
>
>   again.  Bug #27960 by Eric Hankins.
> - `gem query` and friends output now lists platforms.  Bug #27856 by Greg
>     Hazel.   * `gem server` now allows specification of multiple gem dirs for
>     documentation.  Bug #27573 by Yuki Sonoda.   * `gem unpack` can unpack
>     gems again.  Bug #27872 by Timothy
>     Jones.   * `gem unpack` now unpacks
>     remote gems.   * --user-install is no
>     longer the default.  If you really
>     liked it, see
>     Gem::ConfigFile to learn how to set it by default.  (This change was
>     made
>     in 1.3.6)
> - RubyGems now has platform support for IronRuby.  Patch #27951 by Will
>     Green.
>
> Bug fixes:
>
> - Require rubygems/custom_require if --disable-gem was set.  Bug #27700 by   Roger Pack.
> - RubyGems now protects against exceptions being raised by plugins.
> - rubygems/builder now requires user_interaction.  Ruby Bug #1040 by
>     Phillip   Toland.
> - Gem::Dependency support #version_requirements= with a warning.  Fix for old   Rails versions.  Bug
>
>   ## 27868 by Wei Jen Lu.
> - Gem::PackageTask depends on the package dir like the other rake
>     package   tasks so dependencies can be
>     hooked up correctly.
>
> ---
>
> RubyGems installed the following
>   executables:
>           C:/lang/Ruby/bin/gem
>
> RubyGems system software updated
>
> C:>gem list --local | find "rails"
>
> rails (2.3.5)

Comment: You need to indent your paste by a tab or 4 spaces.